# How can I join three tables using MYSQLi?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join

I know this question has been asked before, but I am hoping someone can help me with my particular instance here (it's 5:30 AM and this is due tomorrow. I'm on my last rope here). Here is my code:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);  ini_set('display_errors', 1);

$db = new mysqli('localhost', 'Brendan', 'password', 'Library');

if($db->connect_errno > 0){
    die('Unable to connect to database [' . $db->connect_error . ']');
}

$title = $_GET["title"];

$sql = "SELECT * FROM `BOOK` WHERE `TITLE` like " . $title . " JOIN MANAGES
    ON BOOK.SERIAL_NUM = MANAGES.SERIAL_NUMBER JOIN LIBRARIAN
    ON MANAGES.ID_NUMBER = LIBRARIAN.ID_NUMBER";

if(!$result = $db->query($sql)){
    die('There was an error running the query [' . $db->error . ']');
}


while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
    echo $row['MANAGES.ID_NUMBER'] . "<br>";
}
```

when I run it, I get this:

> There was an error running the query [You have an error in your SQL
>   syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version
>   for the right syntax to use near 'JOIN MANAGES ON BOOK.SERIAL_NUM =
>   MANAGES.SERIAL_NUMBER' at line 1]

Comment: By the way: `$title = $_GET["title"];` + `WHERE TITLE like " . $title . "` = *Say hello to SQL injection*

Comment: @kingkero: you removed the code that shows that there is a SQL injection in the database query. I agree that only pertinent code should be shown, but I think edits of this kind are too substantial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all it's correct, that the where has to come after the joins.
Additionally always make sure you protect your application from [sql injections](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) and use a prepared statement to bind the parameter:

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM `BOOK` JOIN MANAGES
    ON BOOK.SERIAL_NUM = MANAGES.SERIAL_NUMBER JOIN LIBRARIAN
    ON MANAGES.ID_NUMBER = LIBRARIAN.ID_NUMBER 
    WHERE `BOOK`.`TITLE` like ?';

$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param('s', $title);
$stmt->execute();

$result = $stmt->get_result();
```

In your case you directly include `$title` which is defined by the user or could be defined by the user in your sql query.

Comment: 5 upvotes for a [vulnerable answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23105668/383793)... The state the world is in today....

Comment: The problem is that people usually don't care about security until they're directly affected by an attack.

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `BOOK` JOIN MANAGES
ON BOOK.SERIAL_NUM = MANAGES.SERIAL_NUMBER JOIN LIBRARIAN
ON MANAGES.ID_NUMBER = LIBRARIAN.ID_NUMBER 
 WHERE `BOOK`.`TITLE` like '" . $title . "'";
```

`WHERE` in SQL should come after `JOIN` statement.

EDIT: I edit to suggest that this is not SECURE way of doing it, and since the topic is related to only suggest error in your SQL I follow what you write. But please read about SQL injection and update your code for it.

Answer (score 1):

The basic join format for MySQL is:

```
select ... from A
join B1 on ...
join B2 on ...
...
where ...
```

So, put your where after join statement, and try again.

Comment: OP, if you format your query like this - so `JOIN` and `WHERE` start new lines - you'll find it easier to read.