# How to get result from multiple tables

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, phpmyadmin

I have three tables incometax , servicetax and gst in database and a status field in three tables.. i want to know how many status are pending in three tables..

```
<?php
    $sql ="SELECT i.status, s.status, g.status 
    FROM incometax i
    JOIN servicetax s 
    ON i.status = s.status
    JOIN gst g 
    ON s.status= g.status 
    WHERE status='Pending'";
    if ($result=mysqli_query($con,$sql))    
    {
       $rowcount=mysqli_num_rows($result);
       echo "$rowcount";
    }
?>
```

Comment: What is the issue in this query

Comment: probably duplicate of [How can I join three tables using MYSQLi?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23105613/how-can-i-join-three-tables-using-mysqli)

Comment: The joins exist in the provided code, how can it be a duplicate of that question? The author is asking how to get a value from a common column name in each of the tables.

Answer (score 0):

Always prefix column names with table aliases. There are three tables hence three aliases and so there are 3 uniquely identifiable columns with the title status. To locate any of those with a value of pending you need a where clause like this:

```
WHERE i.status = 'pending' OR s.status = 'pending' OR g.status = 'pending'
```

Note that if you require further conditions you may need parentheses

```
WHERE (i.status = 'pending' OR s.status = 'pending' OR g.status = 'pending') AND ....
```